# Issue when plotting Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, matplotlib, plot

You can find below a sample of the dataset I use in my Python script.

https://ufile.io/2ecay

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\YannickLECROART\\Desktop\\comedie.xlsx")
```

Here is a brief look at the dataset.

[image]

date               object
places_occupees     int64
dtype: object

I convert the date colum into datetime type with the following line of code.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

So dtypes gives this:

[131124 rows x 2 columns]

```
date               datetime64[ns]
places_occupees             int64
dtype: object
```

Then I filter by times between 9 and 10 and sort by timestamp.

```
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
idx_0 = df.loc[df.date.dt.hour==9].sort_values('time')
```

That gives the following result:

```
                      date  places_occupees      time
540    2017-01-01 09:00:00              238  09:00:00
111418 2017-03-19 09:00:00              735  09:00:00
20700  2017-01-15 09:00:00              530  09:00:00
109978 2017-03-18 09:00:00              735  09:00:00
22140  2017-01-16 09:00:00              530  09:00:00

[5460 rows x 3 columns]
date               datetime64[ns]
places_occupees             int64
time                       object
dtype: object
```

When I try to plot this I get an error message.

```
plt.plot(idx_0)
plt.show()

AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

I guess this has to do with the 3rd colum time I added to sort data by time.

What should I do now in order to plot on a graph the data I sorted (between 9 and 10 o'clock)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't tell how you attempted to plot it and you also didn't tell what you want to plot?

Comment: I edited my question. What II want to plot is idx_0 I created which the result of filter I applied on the intial dataset.

Comment: `idx_0` has 3 columns and an index. In a usual plot you have an x and a y axis. You plot such plot via `plt.plot(x,y)`. So from the 12 possible combinations you would want to choose one and define x and y accordingly for plotting.